# Special price and discount on invoice

Tags: price, invoice, special-price

In some EU countries, all discounts, including special prices, must be mentioned in invoice. But Magento doesn't display speciall price anywhere in orders. If speciall price is applied, it will display it just as regular price.

The below is an example of order. Actuall product price was 60€ and speciall price was applied. But it won't display this discount anywhere. Is there any simple solution to this problem? At least I would need it inside invoice.

[image]

Comment: I cannot think of an easy solution for that. You may want to have a look at [FireGento_Pdf](https://github.com/firegento/firegento-pdf) though. The PDFs are more configurable and extendable with this extension in place. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

JohnyFree,Magento don't save special price to `sales order and sales  models`.

So you `cannot get special price to invoice`.

Magento, sales item price has `been calculated on final price and final price has  been save on sales_flat_order_item not saving product price`

Comment: I realized the same. Which is very strange, such a big system and it doesn't give support to display discount for product line inside order. I guess I will add new attribute to sales_flat_order table, save value for it within observer and then modify Invoice.php to display both prices in pdf.